# Spring MVC Model life-cicle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a doubt about Model behavior in Spring MVC.

I have a controller class with to handler methods, say:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getExportResults(@RequestParam("token") String token,
        Model model) {

        // ...

        model.addAttribute("task", myObject);

        // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(Model model, HttpServletResponse response)

    // can't find "task" attribute...

}
```

When I put the `"task"` attribute into `model`, in my `getExportResults` I expect to find it into model argument of `getFile` method, but when I try to get it, `"task"` is **null**.
Am I wrong? Maybe model behaviour is not clear to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. Putting something in the model makes it available for the current request only. The goal of adding something into the model is to make it available for the view, in order to generate the HTML page.

Comment: Yes, or keep your app stateless and thus easier to understand and scale, and reload the task from the database in the second request.

Comment: Yes, I think I will load "task" also in the second request. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Model is initialized with every request, each request creates a new model object. The model you are adding your task object is not the same model object you get in getFile method.

If those are 2 different request, which seems like, you may want to put the task object into session and retrieve it from there.

Comment: In Spring MVC, using session is the only way to share objects among different requests?

Comment: not just spring mvc but almost all web frameworks. Either you will need to build it from scracth for every request or share it via session